# NSolve return incorrect roots at high precision but correct at lower precision

Tags: equation-solving

I'm running ver. $13.2$ and working on a $995$-digit precision equation shown at the end of this post and assigned to variable `eqn1`.  Running `NSolve` on `eqn1`:

```
roots1 = x /. NSolve[eqn1, x];
N[roots1, 8] // MatrixForm
```

I obtain the roots shown in the second column of the table below.  Note the 0-precision values which causes the precision of all the roots to drop to 0 and also misses a double root at around $0.164+0.390i$.  However, if I constrain the precision of `eqn1` to just $100$ digits:

```
roots2 = x /. NSolve[SetPrecision[eqn1, 100], x];
N[roots2, 10] // MatrixForm
```

`NSolve` computes the roots to $91$ digits of precision and identifies the double roots $0.164+0.390i$ shown in the third column. And although I could check to make sure the precision is sufficient, I was wondering why `NSolve` is unable to find all the roots given a higher precision equation but finds them at the lower precision.

$$
\small
\begin{array}{ccc}
\text{Num} & \text{995 digit precision} & \text{100 digit precision} \\
\hline
 1 & -3.7108475750749401871-2.1423569012879656878 i & -3.7108476-2.1423569 i \\
 2 & -3.7107592597400160044+2.1425098673435827978 i & -3.7107593+2.1425099 i \\
 3 & -0.50204976759266972259+0.20795114099360870377 i & -0.50204977+0.20795114 i \\
 4 & -0.49813168062118827044-0.17423736842716004144 i & -0.49813168-0.17423737 i \\
 5 & -0.22903491658975639891+0.47543299506924247334 i & -0.22903492+0.47543300 i \\
 6 & -0.16185899605839704663-0.39077043990874804808 i & -0.16185900-0.39077044 i \\
 7 & -0.16185898869989443755-0.39077047685806820510 i & -0.16185899-0.39077048 i \\
 8 & -0.0000883148027959759-4.2848667680991341852 i & -0.0000883-4.2848668 i \\
 9 & 0.\times 10^{-1} & 0.0000883+4.2848668 i \\
 10 &0.\times 10^{-1} & 0.16185899+0.39077046 i \\
 11 & 0.0000883148027959759+4.2848667680991341852 i & 0.16185899+0.39077046 i \\
 12 & 0.22903491658975737805-0.47543299506924210337 i & 0.22903492-0.47543300 i \\
 13 & 0.49813168062118790136+0.17423736842715906197 i & 0.49813168+0.17423737 i \\
 14 & 0.50204976759266911253-0.20795114099360809426 i & 0.50204977-0.20795114 i \\
 15 & 3.7107592597400160044-2.1425098673435827978 i & 3.7107593-2.1425099 i \\
 16 & 3.7108475750749401871+2.1423569012879656878 i & 3.7108476+2.1423569 i \\
\end{array}
$$

Code for 995-digit precision 16-degree function:

```
(2.6963820658987673089162105168431584921342782356592188320579280107001\
2864953670212813602661127763875877306850451990794674429360141886435737\
3131240353773283315092513980212053875565163762725604727896361022247503\
3732288131899289785014924957232256315125428415436629139207247881896152\
4226864443955812406938277766792069557078075383464793873413630934225877\
0910122795621152254707423413634352201851728515176584173266134650108062\
5107985435346558279637230447813097221158815509498048367574786698956361\
3248217296285584227527972724611142980392909457234324643594643145289977\
6187579483054256351463716002275254658049464713110583070140777533545478\
8424521510285613365293707214972854797363386824264315827436917475655102\
4048906550737023166375291932275905127665386185141587374974147059617764\
0393577026598181705414387756666252688670920913516021318733255852712857\
3010183708564393300435222851044860674174255710499231858189113562765933\
4430890079346371981292408401093620203663861066795738948667112179285223\
40007450517049670*10^13 - 
    2.6986627526611047424330793075384598028105775811608651201145237800\
1372798142472606015172730241505819761528996790638758261374537810207483\
9989712925215283823846795652704054581448115785637230378788929562727420\
7301208671048864425640029581148359830863124705364675408343050755649261\
5040540486035128720847360899831418060368672729970056301069932338474711\
5344211881111265468436874437560499846780245828203173550577195281059398\
8675576754879729249787722518128331175424381950252011755522446256093715\
5035198775077852568978112725110287535067656520437402756797746027341886\
8252704382735134624350557920554903659869104809864368704008905219361859\
5979615695980047384070540135587694627772252957188029322347151998369209\
5765531369674463243190350202429514439409463556008304567692016022271499\
5464163980498288610403822338067707780804282541387348373627994418593030\
8275154130022726535049505866682758430690300000835530287943872012249039\
4673994649699155496611179602676633391651138658530930442579186418914514\
82561184542569892357*10^13 I) + \
(2.6655078525968215826636850697558944243375260983562283945859635999870\
1738762908729300029698340785503249963966529011489741410410912011263914\
2729096101812067243061713142796980853530107206460515288048682011550994\
6800370219074781454578215285205854846508956743508977651820288698534347\
5154935109164049144391412749521182266761961196153881982788560632592269\
6837981134998262116180336184438415185933293580230755882799485705161810\
4149782303068580632427656674333012438353118967629386582608756738923118\
4229165981651896783263568767816684196114802599661672156414593233982522\
4511911392932299215753151737685325977101107195445159631274395336456867\
8068933429465626371537098754401123312674076084321205738101691419673099\
8018505040187184206463993165173981411529766844177995118205113927574088\
6303185104591601557485478963745038397064247953940933368860161008679892\
3756001034395563067889092133782100466581767463461883721436986005047046\
9579157366933590298720491502836461202260751474587549096507706055417485\
823121087234589008360*10^14 - 
     1.167026470787144896578336838364801891087603148065622427684080291\
2715043012343588747398741863139353221199525207894065430498843198844536\
7780893711868799610112607093436873356613656832932807580806095054766083\
3697110037690790436491834029991189055014301053600048919875637328730355\
7256031519298971887269269662454277953361365233378935676021466367465427\
1199128478125743290060615814671665050667065585902454816700644185999141\
3952308729417211706091564133521490989405168862169481865112048900301099\
1860487213237010549553661472830250385519630335853295895133431798978266\
5744834864612205602918694504590905545045249307953534986734590009681392\
0631041072675992353870649100061886370957846853755290119006631250241472\
0009899947646984244673538612733855308942087107717979062803127694616038\
5635522335354921423531884902324546622237779436900453733394068551831846\
4642212879504822263786347687679224955937732788910333158038325050357783\
7574309730023378756009081734072101215968571688516060699364938494170122\
7372345957209287017266*10^11 I) x^2 - 
  5 x^3 + (5.\
2043830500665017106332149285797205112108877914674978357021149620988853\
8513375308023275175433626907824113978392974986922464725323004858341158\
9232530198926058980941420220192208713797133891816784715563556180673067\
4388297150678036271233068050552240042731714444882453186329087090254125\
4095256367538164343479438720835724781354050357110289016676260223699738\
2822470253749302356340687260137598313398846341379457604077625673648639\
5234680074557284317419904427848682989311795681242720844655267748826270\
2070731196620338301808182535917253795225517797919521234989578529441400\
3437833691246530058684332685201127514009250948696174588623589522787010\
3944171361003716852590513013869099975964051845889241743038930390575865\
3695350067809121825464537908623940902429501199253611653331180775859727\
0168942428898469274254037230822310788067465601646636292482783976260512\
1357611999473456483796067272457838167668131232572221270285316769931088\
3043752222862935094559242382933075136241036106099847003653213046017029\
646297699517606638*10^16 - 
     2.596107347194203619555168291198327176852078776945166249893930373\
9711358027544922248223779980346549981634375988558071424337166299875177\
8331864616079322763492097705023496459270629223119546671763053209548351\
7149516211267240347545550670229817451460664834979941327516481385666663\
4825799133045276089549410383295836386138968850332298519997225758852873\
7159966168145176717429750921049615766221644095244637039185984752074563\
1941877291115262531501849061715639081006030021468929578504344321974895\
6634741759218468625661206875646344805727576299976093823653757983019463\
3176988060454061673335799670474262647765193807785164025289441448826005\
5885277338494051356870444207440530953019233954640185534156919407918384\
4441550205602044679310105653553668976553047611158394957081601664842277\
1350183534970795625152799098125406311370705643433502905329372872801849\
5840789894151128775355306705873144554451165937142290683398092280387604\
6805203248398597655308352973052109489274615018071110937644113997329319\
2526523932509126661950*10^13 I) x^10 + \
(8.4090195077874434772877262475073826827888566296548118083612754361291\
0923416419818312628913493735679258319493276447412935286553147456854861\
6367782836295229960600445056494330152212041987524377339592039256889125\
2697872649819073873115363715472960031565613101816384903386355334588709\
9600814281267676608017365267940654630324263201469249025805348881833658\
6176347497880947289848893636049215307033495561691255850368912226785329\
2169043192141194627359088154207030538017631744447215642780158136783528\
0343609670623434201847932334572470838243324467052323461171738220178245\
5717727503993995631468173685882598281676384122808867948154602193222890\
8917491924130177874918314207757912172370973725756952787788281806851305\
9145145978327381468641931525547275751831994832595003424268775659398964\
2520927759338906238048312898280112301038577299452596787690604702870349\
9409538513438243781616481418233927968673391627511798253387393455447699\
2674479921645128789157858822626902112040288453560238900960238504634770\
891414469988655960621*10^12 - 
     3.154773921238829531522564977225571190233650740296533695189368056\
1636274443649983527713028525547683842250423391387547680956014812182944\
7382291699760222980911655856251614052385296864820359888820851598198821\
3577056719197936062089590515665966069710883419377620513900331508959179\
3243893635769558211567720909626759400770869886650478664079224956830943\
1401236051037804866930320939047997833437067554800790608483626856959382\
7300636259925274834835557024005405857780420861014265470514436796883850\
2672059856652277804155469972394283069855113264669014923636138950358765\
7649521315602996423412938178131540404036794526822853353853013133053628\
9737039156190072692446272856964570983594078330947460542347842620127683\
4461718593789248648882487357007871180852997591174965647029756060080695\
5270982233138222090580336665035803025318185595726973852881978516448081\
7989254216707775999664825602996420467229888147328926446814412601289030\
7747763927095485548208792922003990323304779073304242834527448051386937\
2005041056042122356267*10^9 I) x^16 == 0
```

Comment: @Michael E2:  Could you explain further your comment?  The zeros with zero precision are obviously not solutions to the equation and `NSolve` completely misses the other two roots which must be double for other constraints on this equation.  Just would have expected `NSolve` to peform better such as reporting insufficient precision or acknowledge the inability to find all the roots.  Also, if I increase the precision of the equation to 2000, then `NSolve' does find all the roots at about $600$ digits of precision.